# Export From Access to Excel

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, dao

I want to export some data in one recordset in Access to Excel.

I know the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet command but it works only with stored queries, and in my case it's a runtime-filtered recordset.

I've tried some codes to do what I want. I can get the data exported but I cannot get the column name from the recordset.

Any suggestion on the commands or how to get those column names from recordset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DAO recordsets have a `name` property you can use.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ARTIKELGRUPPE")
Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Name
Debug.Print rs.Fields(1).Name
```

Output for my table:

```
id
Name
```

Comment: You can do exactly the same with ADO recordsets, they have the ´name´ property as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter a stored query prior to calling transfer spreadsheet

```
Dim myQuery As QueryDef
Set myQuery = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("SampleQuery")
myQuery.SQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE something"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport,acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "SampleQuery", "c:\test.xls"
```